# use differents colors in paper-menu Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, colors, polymer

I'm trying to make a menu using Polymer 1.0
My menu is made like that :

```
<paper-menu>
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu}}" as="item">
  <paper-item>
  <div>{{item.title}}</div>
  </paper-item>
 </template>
</paper-menu>
```

I searched in every paper-menu and paper-item properties, trying some combination, but I don't find anything to apply a specific color to each item (i.e. first item will have blue background when selected, second will be green, ...)

Is there any solution to do this?

thanks

Edit

Here's how  HTML is rendered

```
<paper-menu class="style-scope widget-store x-scope paper-menu-0" role="menu" tabindex="0">
  <div class="selectable-content style-scope paper-menu">
    <paper-item class="style-scope widget-store x-scope paper-item-0" role="option" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="style-scope widget-store">1</span>
    </paper-item>
    <paper-item class="style-scope widget-store x-scope paper-item-0" role="option" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
      <span class="style-scope widget-store">2</span>
    </paper-item>
  </div>
</paper-menu>
```

Comment: Show us how the html is rendered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, if you have a specific need, just add a specific `class` to your element, and then write the according rule in CSS.
You can take a look at how I did in the following component: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/gold-password-input/blob/master/gold-password-input-strength-meter.html
I defined the CSS like this:

```
  .None {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-none-color, --paper-grey-700) !important;
  }
  .VeryWeak {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-veryweak-color, --paper-red-700) !important;
  }
  .Weak {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-weak-color, --paper-orange-700) !important;
  }
  .Medium {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-medium-color, --paper-yellow-700) !important;
  }
  .Strong {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-strong-color, --paper-blue-700) !important;
  }
  .VeryStrong {
    color: var(--gold-password-input-strength-meter-verystrong-color, --paper-green-700) !important;
  }
```

And a binding here:

```
<span id="strengthLabel">
  [[strengthMeterLabels.Label]]:
  <span class$=[[_strengthMeterScore]]>[[_computeStrengthMeterLabel(_strengthMeterScore)]]</span>
  <paper-icon-button icon="info" alt="info" disabled noink></paper-icon-button>
</span>
```

And finally the logic here:

```
// update the zxcvbn score property
switch(result.score) {
  case 0:
    this._strengthMeterScore = 'VeryWeak';
    break;
  case 1:
    this._strengthMeterScore = 'Weak';
    break;
  case 2:
    this._strengthMeterScore = 'Medium';
    break;
  case 3:
    this._strengthMeterScore = 'Strong';
    break;
  case 4:
    this._strengthMeterScore = 'VeryStrong';
    break;
  default:
    this._strengthMeterScore = 'None';
}
```

I hope this help in your use-case!

Comment: Oh, that's perfect.
I see my error, I was trying to change to color for the selected state, that's why it did not work.
I just had a simple css class with color, and it works perfectly ! 

Thanks a lot !